# Confusion About Observers and Unconsumed Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having trouble understanding the statement below and have read it multiple times unfortunately:

> If you never get a computed property, its observers will not fire even
>   if its dependent keys change. You can think of the value changing from
>   one unknown value to another.
>
> This doesn't usually affect application code because computed
>   properties are almost always observed at the same time as they are
>   fetched. For example, you get the value of a computed property, put it
>   in DOM (or draw it with D3), and then observe it so you can update the
>   DOM once the property changes.

This is part of

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/object-model/observers/

An example of an observer is:

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.set('salutation', "Mr/Ms");
  },

  salutationDidChange: function() {
    // some side effect of salutation changing
  }.observes('salutation').on('init')
});
```

Does this mean that if I don't call

`person.get('salutationDidChange')` it will be considered an unconsumed computed property, and it will not execute even if `salutation` changes?

Comment: Why are you asking this? Just run the code if both ways and see if your observer function gets called.

Answer (score 1):

All they are saying is that if you have an observer `function(){}.observes('salutations')` and you have a computed property `salutations` like `function(){}.property('otherValue')`, the observer won't fire when `otherValue` only when the `.property()` has been accessed and it returns a different value.

The example listed isn't related to the headline. A better example would be:

```
var auth = Ember.Object.extend({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  currentUser: function(){
     // When foo.get('currentUser') is accessed I will trigger.
     console.log('currentUser')
  }.property('isAuthenticated'),
  doThing: function(){
    // When the value `currentUser` changes, I will trigger.
    console.log('doThing')
  }.observes('currentUser')
});
```

If `isAuthenticated` changes, `doThing` will not fire until you access `currentUser`. The change to `isAuthenticated` doesn't cascade through properties triggering `doThing` implicitly.